# auth0 authentication issue with tokenNotExpired method

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0

I am trying to authenticate using auth0 from an angular2 application. Bellow is my authentication service (as resources I used [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/04-user-profile) and [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login) and [this](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#checking-authentication-to-hideshow-elements-and-handle-routing)):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService{

    //Configure Auth0
    lock =  new Auth0Lock('my_client_id', 'my_domain', {});

    //Store profile object in auth class
    userProfile: Object;

    constructor(){
        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult)=>{
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) =>{
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    return;
                }
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.userProfile =  profile;
            })
        });
    }

    public login(){
        console.log('Login');
        this.lock.show();
    }

    public isAuthenticated(){
        console.log(tokenNotExpired());
        return tokenNotExpired();
    }

    public logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('profile');
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        this.userProfile =  undefined;
    }
}
```

As auth0 identity provider I use database. I've manage to login using the Auth0 lock object (I am receiving token) but when I want to hide/show some buttons the tokenNotExpired() method always returns false, even after the login.

```
<button md-button (click)="login()" *ngIf="!authService.isAuthenticated()">
  <md-icon class="demo-toolbar-icon">input</md-icon>
  Login
</button>

<button md-button (click)="logout()" *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()">
  Logout
  <md-icon class="demo-toolbar-icon">exit_to_app</md-icon>
</button>
```

Why the tokenNotExpired method returns always false and how to resolve this issue so that I can hide/show elements?

**EDIT**

I added the following code to the authentication service:

```
import { tokenNotExpired, AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        tokenName: 'id_token',
        tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token'))
    }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService{

//Configure Auth0
lock =  new Auth0Lock('my_client_id', 'my_domain', {});
```

Comment: `tokenNotExpired` uses internally the `tokenGetter`. How did you configured it? See angular2-jwt.

Comment: @CSchulz I didn't knew that I must configure `tokenGetter`. I followed the examples from the resources posted. What config is suitable for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you missed the configuration for the `tokenGetter` or the custom token name, here an example how to configure it.

The interesting part is the **tokenName**. I assume that the id_token is the real token.

If you need some other logic to retrieve the token, uncomment `tokenGetter` and implement like you need.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        tokenName: 'id_token',
        //tokenGetter: (() => <whatEverStorage>.getItem('token')),
    }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

[Source](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/#advanced-configuration)

Comment: I think it is more a timing issue. When does the authenticated event from the lock occurs? Does it occur?

Comment: I've linked the click event of the login button to a method. In that method I call the login method from the authentication service(posted code) that pops-up the lock screen. After inserting the credentials(I think this is were the authentication event takes place) I am redirected to my home page. I am receiving a token

Comment: Did you debug the `tokenExpired` method? You can see directly why the method returns the wrong value.

Comment: The `tokenNotExpired` methods accepts parameter: `function tokenNotExpired(tokenName, jwt) {...}`. If no parameter given, the default token name is 'token'. I had to add my token name. Now the method returns true when token is valid

Comment: So that would be your solution. Try it with **id_token**. You can remove in this case the `AuthModule`.